# Add leading zeros until all lines before the comma consist of nine characters and subsequently insert a character every three digits using sed

Tags: sed

The aim is to add leading zeros until all lines before the comma consist of nine characters and subsequently insert a character every three digits using `sed`.

**Input**

```
12345,1s4c3v6s3nh6
123456789,9h5vgbdx34dc
12,7h4f45dcvbgh
1234567,09klijnmh563
```

**Current outcome**

```
[vagrant@localhost ~]$ sed -e 's/\([0-9]\{3\}\),/\/\1\//g' file
12/345/1s4c3v6s3nh6
123456/789/9h5vgbdx34dc
12,7h4f45dcvbgh
1234/567/09klijnmh563
```

**Expected outcome**

```
000/012/345,1s4c3v6s3nh6
123/456/789,9h5vgbdx34dc
000/000/012,7h4f45dcvbgh
001/234/567,09klijnmh563
```

**Note:**

1. `12345` needs to become `000012345` and `12` should result in
   `000000012`. In short, the emphasis is on the number sequence before
   the comma.
2. The format of the lines is always
   `MAX_9_characters,fixed_12_characters`. I.e., e.g.,
   `1234512345,1s4c3v6s3nh6` will never reside in the input file.

The problem is that the number of characters could not be equalized using sed. How could this be accomplished?

Comment: it must be done in `sed` or can use others tools?

Comment: One more thing, do you want that field to always be 10 characters long or can it be longer? I mean, do you need it to have a specific length or do you need to parse the file, find the longest 1st field and pad the rest to that length?

Comment: @terdon Yes that is correct as well. A fixed number is required. I will update the question.

Comment: @Gnouc `sed` is preferred

Comment: Is there a reasonable bound to the length of an input line in advance?

Comment: Every line in your data consists of two comma-separated fields, where the second field is always 12 characters long. Therefore, “all lines are the same length” and “all lines have the same length value in the first field” mean the same thing. Note that your question asks for the first, and the answers (below) give you the second. Also, you never properly answered the question, “do you need it to have a specific length or do you need to parse the file, find the longest 1st field and pad the rest to that length?” I.e., is **9** a magic value, or might there be a line that begins `1234512345`?

Comment: @G-Man if `12345,1s4c3v6s3nh6` then `12345` is the first and `1s4c3v6s3nh6` the second part. The answers below are aimed on the first part, which is extended to `000012345` and subsequently `000/012/345`. Regarding the length, it needs to be specific i.e. `9`. This is independent on the number of characters in the first part, e.g. 3, 5, 6. These always need to be extended to the specific number of characters, i.e., 9.

Comment: (1) If your question is specific to the number 9, then *your question should say so*, rather than just giving examples. (2) I understood what you wanted done with `12345,1s4c3v6s3nh6`. My question is, what happens if there’s a line `1234512345,1s4c3v6s3nh6`? I guess you’re saying that this will never happen. OK, but that should be stated *in the question*.

Comment: @G-Man Thank you for the feedback. The title has been updated and the exact format of the lines which reside in the input file has been described in a note and the example has been added as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your input don't have long sequence number in second field, try:

```
$ sed -e 's|^[^,]*|#000000000&|;s|#[^,]*\(.\{9\}\),|\1,|;s|\([0-9]\{3\}\)|\1/|g;s|/\([^0-9]\)|\1|;s|/$||' file
000/012/345,1s4c3v6s3nh6
123/456/789,9h5vgbdx34dc
000/000/012,7h4f45dcvbgh
001/234/567,09klijnmh563
```

**Explanation**

- `s|^[^,]*|#000000000&|`: we match all thing from start to the first `,`, replace it with a maker `#` and n numbers 0, where n is length we want to pad.
- `s|#[^,]*\(.\{9\}\),|\1,|`: we match all thing from the marker to the first `,`, only keep the last 9 characters before `,`, discard the rest.
- `s|\([0-9]\{3\}\)|\1/|g`: add a `/` each 3 sequence of digits.
- `s|/\([^0-9]\)|\1|;s|/$||`: if after `/` is not a number or `/` is at the end of line, we remove it.

or easier with `perl`:

```
$ perl -F',' -anle '
    $F[0] = sprintf "%09s", $F[0];
    $F[0] =~ s|.{3}|$&/|g;
    chop $F[0];
    print join ",",@F;
' file
000/012/345,1s4c3v6s3nh6
123/456/789,9h5vgbdx34dc
000/000/012,7h4f45dcvbgh
001/234/567,09klijnmh563
```

Comment: Nice, +1. Could you break that down and explain how it works? Also, why is the `-e` needed?

Comment: Ha! We had basically the exact same perl approach :) Clever use of `chop` though.

Comment: @terdon: Add explanation for sed, just my habit when using `-e`. Yeah, yours is shorter and I think faster. TIMTOWTDI!

Comment: I believe that your first `sed` subcommand is equivalent to `s|^|#000000000|`, and that you could remove all (both) `#` characters from the command with no harm.

Comment: Oh! Your `sed` command chokes if there's a three-digit number to the right of the comma.

Comment: @G-Man: Yes, it was noticed in my answer.

Comment: Oh, is *that* what you meant by "long sequence number in second field"? I find that a little cryptic.

Answer (score 3):

This can probably be done in `sed` but it's beyond my sed-fu. Here's a different solution:

```
perl -F, -lane '$F[0]=sprintf("%09s",$F[0]);
                $F[0]=~s#(...)(?!$)#$1/#g;
                print "$F[0],$F[1]"' file
```

The `-a` splits each input line into fields and saves it in the `@F` array. The `-F` sets the field delimiter (`,` here). The `-l` removes trailing newlines and adds a newline to the end of each `print` call and the `n` causes the input file to be read line by line and the script given by `-e` applied to each line.

The script itself does 3 things. First, it uses `sprintf` to add leading `0` to the first field (`$F[0]`). Then, it replaces all sets of three characters in the 1st field (except those at the very end: `(?!$`)`) with themselves followed by a`/`. Finally, it prints the now modified 1st field, a comma and the 2nd field.

Comment: This works as well +1. I have never worked with `perl` before, but copying and pasting the code in the terminal shows the expected outcome and the explanation helps to understand it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Now that the question has been refined, we can simplify Gnouc’s `sed` answer down to

```
sed 's|^|000000000|;s|.*\(...\)\(...\)\(...,\)|\1/\2/\3|' file
```

or, if you want to retain a whiff of a general solution,

```
sed 's|^|000000000|;s|.*\(.\{3\}\)\(.\{3\}\)\(.\{3\},\)|\1/\2/\3|' file
```

These, like at least some of the other answers,
assume that there is only one comma on each line.

Comment: This method works as well +1. Thank you.